# parallel updates to oracle table from spring mvc application

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-mvc, oracle11g

We have an application running in 2 containers/pods. This applications reads request from ActiveMQ and for processing this request this applications needs to update 10 tables. We have these hundreds of ASYNC request in ActiveMQ that needs to be processed in hundreds per second and each request tries to update the 10 tables in one oracle database. Because of these updates to 10 tables at the same fraction of a second some of the request fails frequently with this error "Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource"

Is there a better way to handle these kind of scenarios like a better architecture ?
Is there a better way to handle these kind of scenarios using spring framework?

Answer (score 0):

Your premise is wrong; deadlocks are not caused simply by a large amount of activity on many tables.  They're a special kind of lock that occur when different sessions try to lock the same row in a *different order*.  When that happens, the only solution is to kill one of the sessions to release the lock.

The first step in investigating deadlocks is to look in the alert log and find the trace file generated by a deadlock.  It will show the statements and objects involved.  If you're lucky, the mistake is caused by a missing foreign key index or a bitmap index on a transactional table, which can be resolved with a simple DDL change.

If you're unlucky, the application is changing tables in different orders.  In that case, you'll need to change the application to always process changes the same way.  I don't think I can offer any advice for that, it depends entirely on your application.